# bundle exec jekyll serve not working locally

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages

I am following [this link](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/creating-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll) to setup my personal website on Github. The website has been deployed successfully and I can visit it now.

My ruby version is `3.3.0` and my gem version is `3.5.4`. I have also added `webrick` mentioned in this [link](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/testing-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll#building-your-site-locally).

However, I can't build it locally after running `bundle install` and `bundle exec jekyll serve`. The error is

```
jekyll 3.9.3 | Error:  undefined method `[]' for nil
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/logger.rb:384:in `level': undefined method `[]' for nil (NoMethodError)

    @level_override[Fiber.current] || @level
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/log_adapter.rb:43:in `adjust_verbosity'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/configuration.rb:157:in `config_files'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll.rb:113:in `configuration'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/command.rb:43:in `configuration_from_options'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:89:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/bin/jekyll:25:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/bin/jekyll:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:451:in `exec'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:28:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:527:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:34:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:584:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:28:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.5/exe/bundle:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:117:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.5/exe/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
```

My `_config.yml` is

```
# Welcome to Jekyll!
#
# This config file is meant for settings that affect your whole blog, values
# which you are expected to set up once and rarely edit after that. If you find
# yourself editing this file very often, consider using Jekyll's data files
# feature for the data you need to update frequently.
#
# For technical reasons, this file is *NOT* reloaded automatically when you use
# 'bundle exec jekyll serve'. If you change this file, please restart the server process.
#
# If you need help with YAML syntax, here are some quick references for you:
# https://learn-the-web.algonquindesign.ca/topics/markdown-yaml-cheat-sheet/#yaml
# https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/
#
# Site settings
# These are used to personalize your new site. If you look in the HTML files,
# you will see them accessed via {{ site.title }}, {{ site.email }}, and so on.
# You can create any custom variable you would like, and they will be accessible
# in the templates via {{ site.myvariable }}.

title: username
email: username@gmail.com
description: >- # this means to ignore newlines until "baseurl:"
  Write an awesome description for your new site here. You can edit this
  line in _config.yml. It will appear in your document head meta (for
  Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description.
baseurl: / # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: https://username.github.io # the base hostname & protocol for your site, e.g. http://example.com
twitter_username: username
github_username:  username

# Build settings
theme: minima
plugins:
  - jekyll-feed

# Exclude from processing.
# The following items will not be processed, by default.
# Any item listed under the `exclude:` key here will be automatically added to
# the internal "default list".
#
# Excluded items can be processed by explicitly listing the directories or
# their entries' file path in the `include:` list.
#
exclude:
  - .sass-cache/
  - .jekyll-cache/
  - gemfiles/
  - Gemfile
  - Gemfile.lock
  - node_modules/
  - vendor/bundle/
  - vendor/cache/
  - vendor/gems/
  - vendor/ruby/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Fixed by downgrading ruby from 3.3.0 to 3.2.3.

While this technically *does* work, I don't know that it's a best or recommended practice.

I was struggling with the same issue from above post, and I've recently published [a post on medium](https://medium.com/@ritviknag/ruby-versioning-trouble-with-jekyll-github-pages-fd2748bf4e1d) (actually my first ever post) collecting my findings.

**TL;DR** -
To make a long story short, for easiest way to manage `ruby` versions, I suggest to install and use **`rbenv`** to manage **ruby** versions, instead of installing via `brew` or other.

Here's how - don't forget to remove `$` from commands:

```bash
$ brew install rbenv ruby-build
$ echo 'eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"' >> ~/.zshrc
$ source ~/.zshrc
```

Then install desired `ruby` version:

```
$ rbenv install 3.2.3
```

Finally, either set installed `ruby` in *global*, or *local* scope, or *both*:

```
$ rbenv global 3.2.3
$ rbenv local 3.2.3
$ ruby -v
ruby 3.2.3
```

Finally install `bundler` gem:

```
$ gem install bundler
$ bundle -v
Bundler version 2.5.5
```

Now we're good to go!

Comment: Perfect response, I've been digging around for way too long after either `brew` or something else suddenly broke my `ruby` or `bundle` installation. This fixed it immediately.

Answer (score 6):

Fixed by downgrading ruby from 3.3.0 to 3.2.3.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this work-around! I had exactly the same issue, fixed it by using 3.2.3 too.